# How to execute script only if website loaded from my refer websites?

Tags: php

I want that my script work only if the user came from a specific website. Like I have a website example.com, so if user came through example.com then only script runs else give error.

I am currently using this code as shown below.

```
 $referer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 $refer = $referer['host'];

 if  ($refer == "example.com") { 

 }
 else {
```

This code works but many times website doesn't pick refer. So Is their any way that Script Run even if the tab opened in Background rather than refer, like 2 conditions.

Like: If refer is example.com = Script Runs OR If example.com website opened in background then also, Script Runs.

Comment: Not if there is no referer, because `undefined != "example.com"` so the test will be false and your `else` code will run.  However, a program or library like cURL can lie and send any referer header that they want to.

Comment: I want that my Script only Loads if any of 2 conditions meet. What code should i edit.

Comment: The server scripts won't know how do you open the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note this answer is valid if you have access to both example.com and example2.com

[image]

First, you need to send a request from example.com to example2.com as shown in the above picture then save this request to the database.

Now you have the user IP address and last time he/she opened example.com so you can know if he/she is currently opening example.com by comparing the last time example.com sent Ajax request about this user (identified by IP address) and current time (so if different is between 1-2s so inevitably example2.com is in background).

and your code should look like this

```
$current_user_ip = get_ip(); // write a function that can get user IP

$fetch = ['ip_addr' => 'xxxxxx','timestamp' => '556654646']; //SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE ip_addr = $get_ip;

$user_ip = $fetch['ip_addr'];
$timestamp = $fetch['timestamp'];

$referer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$refer = $referer['host'];

if  ($refer == "example.com" ||  ($current_user_ip == $user_ip && (time() - $timestamp) <= 1 /* 1 sec */  ) ) { 

}else{

}
```

Comment: Not Working Bro,
The Refer works Perfectly no Doubt. But I want that also, if that website "example.com" opened in background(like no refer needed)  then also script Runs. As lot of time $refer doesn't Works.

Comment: Do you have access to both website ?